# How to make a public forked repository to personal private repository in github?

Tags: github, repository, git-fork, private-repository

I have to fork a public repository from another github account in which the visibility cannot be change to private. But after forking it into my account, I need to make the repository to private. How should I do this?

I only tried changing the visibility. That is already set to public and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at this: https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/github-how-to-make-a-fork-of-public-repository-private-6ee8cacaf9d3. Should provide you with the direction you need.